# REVIT : Is there a way to use a variable in an annotation to set the heights of certain objects?

Tags: revit

We have a series of objects (wall outlets, data ports, etc) that have certain heights pre-decided for them. Is there a way to enter a variable in the DIMENSIONS that is set somewhere else in the project so that IF we adjust the variable, all of the objects that have that variable in their DIMENSIONS will auto-adjust to the right height?

For instance... I want all wall outlets to be 4' from the ground. I would like to create a DIMENSION from the top of the wall outlet box to the ground. I would like to also enter a variable instead of distance in the DIMENSION. So instead of entering 4' 0" and have the outlet auto-move to 4' from the ground I want to enter $WALLOUTLET and then elsewhere in the project find the $WALLOUTLET variable and set it to (4' 0"). Then if something changes, I can just adjust the $WALLOUTLET variable from (4' 0") to (3' 6") and all of the objects using that variable auto-adjust to 3' 6".

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  This is exactly what Global Parameters can do.  See: [About Global Parameters](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-Model/files/GUID-1AA9B2DC-C08B-458E-BA93-C72C109D61C8-htm.html).

Once created, you can associate a dimension with a global parameter.  When the value for the global parameter is changed, all dimensions associated with the global parameter will update [Use global parameter with a dimension](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-Model/files/GUID-4FF132BC-519A-4D9F-B733-DC33D0FD995A-htm.html).

Or, if you create a family with an instance parameter for its height, you can associate a global parameter with this instance parameter [Use global variable with a instance parameter](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-Model/files/GUID-C6AF47D9-B4C3-4101-842C-81FDDF61FFFF-htm.html).